# PHP Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageOrientation

Tags: php, imagick

Imagick module is installed and running however when trying to use this method it returns undefined. I also need to use the setImageOrientation method which doesn't seem to be defined either.

These functions are clearly in the php.net documentation. Can anyone figured this out?

phpinfo

```
 imagick

imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.1.2
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.2.8 05/07/12 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2006 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    05/07/12
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    153
ImageMagick supported formats   A, ART, AVI, AVS, B, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, C, CACHE, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCX, DNG, DOT, DPS, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, HISTOGRAM, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, JNG, JPEG, JPG, K, LABEL, M, M2V, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MSL, MTV, MVG, NULL, O, OTB, OTF, P7, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PFA, PFB, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, TIFF, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMZ, WPG, X, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

Comment: What is the web service iis / apache , sometime iis can serve different php version for different websites and where is your code ?

Comment: The module also requires some binaries to be present on your OS - take a look at [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.requirements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed this by upgrading ImageMagick on the OS.

This was also difficult since the downloaded binaries on the ImageMagick website don't install well.

I followed this guide and re-installed the pecl package for imagick after.

http://www.webdesignblog.asia/operating-systems/linux-os/updateinstall-imagemagick-centos-5-centos-6/#sthash.yOeyz6bO.zRGxztJh.dpbs

Comment: The version of ImageMagick you listed, "6.2.8" is far older than 05/07/12 The change log says it would have been release in 2007 or so: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have the ImageMagick console application, not the php module.

In that case you have to call imagemagick with `exec()` or `passthru()` or something like that.

-

## Installing ImageMagick PHP Module on ubuntu or debian

`sudo apt-get install php5-imagick`

Comment: I do have the php module installed and also the library installed. I'm on Cent OS 5.10

Comment: The answer is actually to update the ImageMagick version installed on the OS to at lease 6.6

Comment: Yes I just posted the answer. Thanks for your help though I appreciate the feedback :)